# tkinter keyboard interrupt isn't handled until tkinter frame is raised

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboardinterrupt

I have a GUI application written with python+tkinter.  In my workflow, I generally start the gui from the commandline, do some things in the gui and then I find myself navigating to other terminal windows to do some work.  Inevitably, I want to shut down the GUI at some point, and out of habit I often just navigate to the terminal that started the GUI and send a KeyboardInterrupt (Ctrl-c).  However, This interrupt is not recieved until I raise the GUI window in the Window manager.  Does anyone know why this happens?  If the gui is started in a single function, is there a simple workaround -- `multiprocessing` maybe?

Comment: see http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_frm/thread/714cbada9a364d7e/ebf5db79b469661f?lnk=gst&q=tkinter+signal#ebf5db79b469661f

Comment: @nooboddy -- great find.  If you post the link as an answer, we can accept it which might make it easier for someone else looking for the same thing to find.

Comment: "Duplicate": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784232/tkinter-keyboardinterrupt-taking-a-while

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the newsgroups:

> I'm using Python 1.5 under Redhat Linux 5.0.  I'm trying to figure out
> the best way to trap a SIGINT (or Ctrl-C) when using tkinter.  To
> illustrate the problem I have, do the following ...
>
> -- Build Python-1.5 with tkinter enabled.
>
> -- Go into the Demo/tkinter/guido directory under the Python-1.5    build tree.
>
> -- Type "python imageview.py image-file", where "image-file" is the    full pathname of a displayable image.
>
> -- Once the image pops up, make sure that the window focus is    held by the xterm window from which the "python ..." command    was just
> now invoked.
>
> -- Hit Ctrl-C.
>
> At this point, nothing happens.  The Ctrl-C seems to be ignored. But
> now ...
>
> -- Without hitting any more keys on the keyboard, set the window    focus to the displayed image window.
>
> As soon as that window gets the focus, the Ctrl-C takes effect.
>
> My question is this: is there any way to restructure the
> "imageview.py" program so that it will respond to SIGINT (Ctrl-C)
> immediately, without having to set the window focus to the displayed
> image first?
>
> Thanks in advance for any help you folks can give me.
> ---- What you're seeing is caused by the way signal handlers are handled. You're stuck in the Tcl/Tk main loop, and signal handlers are
> only handled by the Python interpreter.  A quick workaround is to use
> after() to schedule a dummy function to be called once a second or so
> -- this will make it *appear* that your signal is handled in a timely manner.
>
> --Guido van Rossum