# KeyboardInterrupt not catching exception

Tags: python, pyautogui

I've read through various threads and the official documentation and yet I can't seem to stop this thread by hotkey. I need to right-click on the running code in vscodes output window and select stop code run.

Ctrl+C and Delete aren't stopping the code from running. Ideally, I'd like to know how to change the keypress to stop the code from running.

I use this in open CV and I was hoping to something similar with pyautogui.

```
if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
    break`
```

The loop I'm struggling with:

```
try:
    while True:   
        for image in image_list:
            name = image
            location = py.locateCenterOnScreen(image, confidence=0.9)
            print(name + " Found at: " + str(location))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
    print("Interrupted")
```

I think the exception is "inside" the loop so it should be catching but nothing happens when I try and exit/break.

Comment: Is it possible that your shell is losing focus, causing the Ctrl-C event to go to a different window?

Comment: Double checked, definitely still in focus. It doesn't actually change!

Comment: I think this probably has less to do with pyautogui, actually, than with whatever GUI toolkit you're using, which might have its own means of handling SIGINT that are not compatible with catching `KeyboardInterrupt`.  See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66788780/982257

Comment: I can use the inbuild vscode interrupt but I was hoping to be able to define my own hotkeys to stop specific threats rather than all threads/scripts at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using **Run Code** not **Run Python File in Terminal**.

**Run Code** is provided by the extension **Code Runner**, which will only show results in OUTPUT ***and not accept input***.